# image carousel in bootstrap card with php

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using php to show images from database. I'm trying to make a carousel, because now my images are under each other. I don't really understand how should I do that because I use $row['image'] only once to fetch data inside a while and carousel needs more classes with active tag aswell. This is how it looks like now:

the end of the php:

```
...
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
$image = $row['image'];
$data[] = $row;
?>
```

```
<?php
echo "<img class='card-img-top' style='padding-bottom: 5px;' src='" . $image . "' />";
}
?>
```

this is how it looks now:
[image: image1]

and this is how it should look:
[image: image2]

The carousel I'd like to use: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel

The carousel html:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=777&fg=555&text=First slide" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=666&fg=444&text=Second slide" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=555&fg=333&text=Third slide" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are different divs. But I can't use the $image more than once. So how should I implement it?

Comment: `card-img-top` class is not for carousel images, reread the [official docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/) there is examples.

Comment: My problem is that I can't implement the carousel classes, because those contain "active" and inactive classes, and I can't use more classes. And also, sometimes a card contains 5 images, but sometimes 0-1-2-3-4.

Comment: the active in `<div class="carousel-item active">` can be set once by looking at the key in the foreach loop or a flag before the while etc, i.e if its 0 output class.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Collect items and buttons from DB, make sure that only first item/button has `active` class. Working sample by linked code:

```
<?php
  
$carouselItems = '';
$carouselButtons = '';

$i = 0;
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $class = ($i == 0) ? 'active' : '';
    $carouselButtons .= "<li data-target='#demo' data-slide-to='{$i}' class='{$class}'></li>";
    $carouselItems .= "<div class='carousel-item $class'>
            <img src='{$row['image']}' width='1100' height='500'>
        </div>";
    var_dump($row);
    $i++;

}
?>
<body>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        /* Make the image fully responsive */
        .carousel-inner img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php echo $carouselButtons; ?>
    </ul>
    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php echo $carouselItems; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
```